# Meaning of "io" in Christmas carol

Tags: meaning

The carol [Adeste Fideles](https://genius.com/Celtic-woman-adeste-fideles-lyrics) includes the line "Cantet nunc io chorus angelorum". What does "io" mean?

Comment: c.f. Ding Dong Merrily on High, with the line "And io, io, io by priest and people sungen"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Iō* is an interjection, defined in [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dio1) as expressing joy, like English "Hurrah!"; or pain, like English "Oh!"; or hurriedly calling to someone, like English "Come quick!"

Some books with the words to *Adeste Fideles,* like [this one](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Latin_Leaflet/gXcyAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA31&printsec=frontcover), put *io* in quotes like this:

[image: Cantet nunc “Io!”]

Frederick Oakeley's English translation renders the first two lines:

> Sing, choirs of angels, sing in exultation;

A literal translation would be:

> May the choir of angels now sing "Io!"

or:

> May the choir of angels now sing "Hurrah!"

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the ritualistic exclamation, much like in **io Saturnalia**, the line is translated as "Sing choir of angels" but the Latin says "Now let the chorus of angels sing" so it seems to be little more than filler.

The only other explanation (and this would be a stretch) is that it is a weird spelling of **eo** dative of is/ea/id, i.e. sing *to him* but I highly doubt that, especially since it would be ii, since eo is the ablative.

So I'd take it as the Latin equivalent of the "O" in O come all ye faithful, doesn't really have any consequence on the words, and is little more than a la or oh or something similar.

Also, looking in Lewis and Short's we have *miles, io, magna voce, triumphe, canet* so it seems to be used with cano/canto.